# Delay removing element from DOM after $destroy has been triggered on current scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, destroy, ng-animate

In AngularJS, is it possible to **delay removing the element from DOM** after `$destroy` has been triggered on current scope?

My intention is to keep the the element in the DOM until something happens, after the `$destroy` event. `ngAnimate` does something similar when it performs the leave animation, it keeps the element "alive" until the animation is complete and it destroys it only after. Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour **without** `ngAnimate`? Maybe using something like a promise in the `$scoope.$on("$destroy", ...)`?

I tried this code which obviously didn't work:

```
  scope.$on "$destroy", ->
    deferred = $q.defer()

    setTimeout ->
      deferred.resolve true
    , 400

    deferred.promise
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `$destroy` event is triggered in response to the element being removed from the DOM, not the other way around.

Perhaps the real fix is to avoid removing the element in the first place. For example, can you show/hide the element rather than removing the underlying data?

Comment: Not exactly, the `$destroy` event is triggered **before** the `leave` animation even begins, while the element is removed **after** the animation is done. I actually wanted to do create something like ngAnimate, to perform some animations on `enter` and `leave`, because ngAnimate's scripts seem to have a large impact on performance right before the animation begins (quite visible on mobile devices) :-)